# Proper way to parse the body of an error with Spring's RestTemplate

Tags: java, json, spring, resttemplate

I'm using the `@Valid` annotation on the `@RequestBody` argument which uses Hibernate Validation, to ensure it's validated:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> register(@RequestBody @Valid RegistrationModel registration) { ...
```

Following the recommendations of the Spring Rest book, I'm catching that exception and turning it into a nice JSON error message that looks like this:

```
{
  "title": "Validation Failed",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "Input validation failed",
  "timeStamp": 1505345551757,
  "developerMessage": "org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException",
  "errors": {
    "hashedPassword": [
      {
        "code": "NotNull",
        "message": "must not be null"
      }
    ],
    "organization": [
      {
        "code": "NotBlank",
        "message": "must not be blank"
      }
    ],
    "name": [
      {
        "code": "NotBlank",
        "message": "must not be blank"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

On the client side, I'm doing this to make the call:

```
Object result = restTemplate.postForObject("http://localhost:8080/v1/registration", registration, Object.class);
```

Using `Object` until I define exactly on the representation of the response. When there's a validation error though, I get a 400 error which throws a `HttpClientErrorException`.

`HttpClientErrorException` has a `getResponseBodyAsString()` that responds with the JSON I pasted above. I could manually parse it, but I was wondering what's the most *correct* way to parse it. RestTemplate clearly has a mechanism for automatically parsing responses when there's no errors. Does it have something for errors?

Comment: Can't you just use `ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
String error= ex.getResponseBodyAsString();
MyError obj = om.readValue(error, MyError .class);` ?

Comment: I can *just* do many things. I don't know what this ObjectMapper is, I could do the same thing with Gson, which is what I'm using in to serialize and deserialize JSON. But my question is not how to do it but how to it properly following the RestTemplate intent. Did they just abandon parsing errors and I have to solve it myself?

Comment: @pupeno did you find an answer in the end? I'm in the same situation